# deploying osgi war bundle

Tags: osgi, springsource-dm-server

I have deployed a standard war file as an osgi bundle into equinox using bnd to create a war bundle.  Whilst it deploys ok and I can run the app, I cannot see any images or css files.  I have deployed catalina-start as an osgi bundle and am using spring-web-extender as the bridge.  The image/css files are located at the root of the war file

```
root
|_images
|_css
|_META-INF
|_WEB-INF
```

I have seen others deploy images and css files in fragment bundles, but I would have thought this should just work.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: More information please. What is the error message (if any)? How do you reference the static resources from your Java code?

Comment: Hi, i just get 404 error when the jsp tries load css, images etc.  I works fine though if I deploy using Jetty bundle.

Answer (score 2):

As alternative, you can try Eclipse Jetty Web engine 7.x [1] that was redesigned to support OSGi Web Application Bundles (OSGi Enterprise 4.2:128). I use Jetty and do not have any problems with WAR static resources (images, scripts etc.)

[1] - http://eclipse.org/jetty/

Regards,
Dmytro

Comment: Hi,  I have since switched to using a jetty 6.x bundle and static resources now resolve fine, thanks.